# promise in Nodejs api design

Tags: node.js, q

I am just started using Q library for the promises. I have this common pattern in most of the api's.

```
userAction1(params)
.then(function(result){
    response.json(result);
},function(err){
    response.json(err);
});

userAction2(params)
.then(function(result){
    response.json(result);
},function(err){
    response.json(err);
});
```

I want to move the last part to some common method and call it instead of repeating it. Little confused about what should be signature of that function. Anyone went through this problem before?

Comment: If your environment is node, why are you using Q? There's native support for "real" promises

Comment: @Amit Promise libraries usually have far more functionality than native. Also not everybody is using the same version of Node, promises were only introduced in `0.11.13`. It's not uncommon to see `10.x` environments.

Comment: @BenFortune - You're correct, that's why asked.. If it's for a good reason then great, otherwise user should probably switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the "last part", I assume you mean the error handling function.

You can shorten it somewhat by passing the method as a reference.

If you're not doing anything else in your function, it would look like this.

```
userAction1(params)
    .then(response.json, response.json);
```

Comment: That definitely gave me some idea, I have created new function which takes the promise & response as param. So I just pass someFunc(userAction1,response), removed some duplication.